# Scripting SQLite with dot commands

Tags: sqlite, scripting

Is it possible to write scripts that contain SQLite dot commands ( vis. `.read file.sql; .separator ,; .import file.csv;` )?

I'm building and repeatedly rebuilding an SQLite database and need to type in roughly twenty four dot command statements every time I rebuild the database. It would be really nice if I could put those commands in a script and have SQLite read them.

Is there a way to put dot commands ( *not* SQL statements ) into a script and have SQLite run them?

I'm on Mac OS X using bash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I searched the Internet for an answer last night and found nothing. Of course, today after posting this question I try again--[and find an adequate response almost immediately.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660320/how-to-automate-a-process-with-the-sqlite3-exe-command-line-tool)

The gist of it? Put your commands in a text file and direct it to SQLite using the input file descriptor, or just script everything in a bash script.

#### First Method:

`sqlite3 database.db < commands.txt`

#### Second Method:

```
#!/bin/bash --
sqlite3 -batch $1 <<"EOF"
CREATE TABLE log_entry ( <snip> );
.separator "\t"
.import logfile.log log_entry
EOF
```

And then on the command line:

```
import.sh database.db
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, which I consider simpler, you can just use the `.read` command. From the command line of your OS (terminal in Mac OS X), type:

```
sqlite3 yourdatabase.db ".read script_full_of_dot_commands"
```

It will start `sqlite3`, use the mentioned database, perform all of the commands in `script_full_of_dot_commands`, and leave.

For instance, let's assume you have the following files:

**script_full_of_dot_commands**: A file with both `.commands`and `SQL commands`:

```
.read file.sql
.separator ","
.import file.csv t
.headers on
.separator "|"
SELECT name, a FROM t WHERE a < 2 ;
SELECT count(*) FROM t2;
```

**file.sql**: A file with just SQL commands.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
CREATE TABLE t (a integer PRIMARY KEY, name varchar);
CREATE TABLE t2 (b integer PRIMARY KEY);
```

**file.csv**: a data file to fill a table

```
1,One
2,Two
3,Three
4,Four
```

The result of performing

```
sqlite3 yourdatabase.db ".read script_full_of_dot_commands"
```

is

```
name|a
One|1
count(*)
0
```

---

Check also: [Running a Sqlite3 Script from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758769/running-a-sqlite3-script-from-command-line) from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

One more scriptable way to provide SQLite dot commands:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite < <(echo -e ".read file.sql \n.separator ',' \n.import file.csv")
```

You can also mix in SQL commands. Just be sure that the `echo -e "…"` command prints things the way you would write them into the SQLite command-line client.

Advantages:

- No need for an extra file.
- No need for the `<<"EOF" … EOF` HERE document syntax. It works, but I always find multi-line shell commands messy to work with when copy&pasting into a terminal.

Explanations:

- This uses Bash process substitution `<(…)` to provide a file input without needing a file on disk.
- The separator between dot commands is a newline right before the command, which we generate here with `echo -e "\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

After being frustrated with this for over an hour today, I found that individually quoting multiple arguments also works:

`sqlite3 -echo -bail exifdata.db '.trace ./exifdata.log' '.read ./exifdata.sql'`

As opposed to grouping the dot commands into a single set of quotes:

`sqlite3 -echo -bail exifdata.db '.trace ./exifdata.log .read ./exifdata.sql'`

Which just responded with the somewhat unhelpful error `Usage: .trace FILENAME`

---

In fact, I am delighted to report that this also works:

```
insertrow() {                                                                   
    SQL="INSERT INTO exifdata (md5, path, bytes, dtcreated, exifhash, exifdata)"
    SQL="$SQL VALUES (:md5, :path, :bytes, :dtcreated, :exifhash, :exifdata)"
    sqlite3 $GLOBAL_OPTS "$CMD_OPTS" \
        ".param init" \
        ".param set :md5 $1" \
        ".param set :path '$2'" \
        ".param set :bytes $3" \
        ".param set :dtcreated '$4'" \
        ".param set :exifhash $5" \
        ".param set :exifdata '$6'" \
        "$SQL" \
        ".param clear"
}
```